# How to pass a C structure in Python

Tags: python, c, function, structure, ctypes

I am trying to pass a structure into a function using python. Currently, my code is:

```
import ctypes

Mydll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("c\...place")
success=Mydll.ConnectToServer

Class PULSETRIGGER_SETUP(ctypes.structure):
    _fields_ = [("dpulseFrequency", ctypes.c_double),
                ("iPulsesA",ctypes.c_int)
                ("iPulsesB",ctypes.c_int)]

sPulseTriggerSetup=PULSETRIGGER_SETUP(200.0,2,2)
print(Mydll.PulseTriggerSetupSet(ctypes.byref(sPulseTriggerSetup)))#-1
print(Mydll.PulseTriggerSetupSet(ctypes.addressof(sPulseTriggerSetup)))#-1
print(Mydll.PulseTriggerSetupSet(ctypes.pointer(sPulseTriggerSetup)))#-1
print(Mydll.PulseTriggerSetupSet(sPulseTriggerSetup))#WindowsError: Exception: access violation reading 0X00000000
```

When I run this code, the errors produced by each method of passing the PULSETRIGGER_SETUP strucure is shown as comments.

The PulseTriggerSetupSet function is:

```
int PulseTriggerSetupSet(PULSETRIGGER_SETUP &sPulseTriggerSetup)
```

where -1 is an error and 0 is success. The C structure for PULSETRIGGER_SETUP is:

```
typedef struct { 
    double dPulseFrequency; 
    int iPulsesA; 
    int iPulsesB; 
} PULSETRIGGER_SETUP;
```

Is there a better way to create the sPulseTriggerSetup structure or to pass it into the PulseTriggerSetupSet function?

Comment: `success=Mydll.ConnectToServer` ... what is this supposed to be?

Comment: We're running hardware across a server. It just connects to another computer that runs the function, I believe.

Comment: You're not calling the function.

Comment: Did you declare POINTER(PULSETRIGGER_SETUP) to be an argument of the function? If not, you won't follow the right ABI.

Comment: How would I declare it an argument? When I load the library, I thought it sets up all the functions and their arguments.

Comment: Please read the documentation of ctypes. It's clearly explained. And no, it is not set up automagically, the C-ABI doesn't support any reflection. If it would, you wouldn't even need to define structures yourself, but import them from the lib as well.

Comment: BTW, that function declaration looks rather like C++ instead of C. Do you have a `extern "C"` declaration around it's declaration?

Comment: @deets, declaring a pointer argument is not necessary if using `byref`. However, parameters should be declared for type safety. Also, if the library didn't use `extern "C"` here, the name of the symbol would be mangled and `Mydll.PulseTriggerSetupSet` would raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @eryksun If it's not C++ (your argument is striking), I just wonder what the & in the parameter declaration is for. I'm at least not aware that it's allowed (and so is clang with a small test program). And you are right, the declaration seems only necessary for return-types, I confused that.

Comment: @deets, for sure it's C++ but the prototype has to be declared in an `extern "C" {}` block.

Comment: @erkysun but even with a prototype given in extern C, you sure can't have a reference argument?

Comment: @deets, I don't like it, but it could have a C API header that declares it as `PULSETRIGGER_SETUP *`. As far as ctypes is concerned, it's just like any other pointer argument. The OP never got back to me regarding whether `Mydll.ConnectToServer` is actually being called. If it isn't, then the error could simply be that it's not connected.

Comment: @eryksun that would work? Strange. It would give the illusion of a reference, where the callsite can pass in a `nullptr`. I wouldn't use that. But if it works....

Comment: I was looking at the main program which I typed this up from. It's success=Mydll.ConnectToServer(), which then just returns -1 if it doesn't connect, so I assume it does. I'll try creating a header or changing other parts of the code. Thanks for trying to help both of you

Comment: A header is only required to call this API from C. Python ctypes uses the application binary interface (ABI), so passing `byref(sPulseTriggerSetup)` should work. I just tested it on a DLL I created that uses the same struct and (dubious) function signature. I say it's dubious because it really shouldn't be using a C++ reference parameter in a C API. That said, it did work. I tested the DLL in both  x86 and x64 versions.